# Render an SVG with filter effects to PNG

Tags: svg, graphics, 2d, skia

I would like to render an SVG I've created to a hi-res (600 DPI) PNG. This SVG has filter effects, specifically gaussian blur.

Ideally rendering could be done via the command line.

I know the SVG is renderable because **you can open it in Chrome/Chromium and the output I'd like to see is there**.

## Things I've tried:

Importing to Adobe Illustrator

svg2png

Imagemagick

Inkscape

Other command-line tools and programs I'm forgetting right now. Basically anything you could find with Google.

## Current path I'm pursuing but stuck on:

Knowing that Chromium can render the SVG just fine and that it's open-source, I figured I'd download the library Chromium depends on to render SVGs (Skia, https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/) and use it to output a PNG. So far I've succeeded in installing Skia and running the very first example. I've found an example that renders an SVG (https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/samplecode/SampleSVG.cpp?r=875) but haven't successfully run it on my OSX machine with the latest updates to XCode and command-line tools. A modified version of that example (with gyp file) that outputs a PNG would be amazing.

## Other ideas that might work:

Getting pixel data from Chrome (how would I do that? A simple screenshot isn't enough because of the resolution of the image. I also want a scriptable, repeatable process.)

Using other graphics library that can render SVG. Maybe this comes from other web browsers, maybe not.

Comment: Example of an SVG with blur effect: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gqc4sf1x1irhsm/blue.svg?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work nicely:

```
webkit2png -F blue.svg -o rendered
```

The `-F` says to generate the `Full` resolution PNG and no thumbnails, and the `-o` specified that the output filename will be `rendered-full.png`.

[image]

I have reduced the size so it fits on Stack Overflow, but the command shown actually gives the full-resolution 2880x2880 image.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to control DPI? I'd like a super-high-DPI version.

Comment: For others reading this, you can use the  `-z 5` argument to increase DPI, where 5 is the zoom level.